# Contact point detection

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, physics, physics-engine, physx

I have hundreds of 3D models. When these models come into contact with each other, I want to determine the exact point where they contact each other.
Since I have so many models, I cannot create primitive colliders for all of them.
Is there a chance to collide two non-convex colliders with each other and detect the collision point?

Comment: Not really as this is quite computation heavy .. do you need this Realtime or is some compute delay okey?

Comment: There may be a heavy calculation delay, that's not a problem.

Comment: I mean worst case: Iterate all triangles and do a manual triangle-triangle intersection ... in a first iteration check whether objects are close enough at all (e.g. bounds-bounds intersection) and only for those do the triangle check ... depends a bit on your exact use case ... might even be able to speed it up and parallelize things a lot using burst or compute shaders

Comment: alternatively throw it into [`Geometry3Sharp`](https://discussions.unity.com/t/triangle-intersection-using-geometry3sharp-library/217036) it has built-in Unity integrations ... it's quite old though and by now there might be better approaches (e.g. I think burst wasn't a thing back then)